# Frontend with more api recorded on AAD (Azure Active Directory)

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I've a problem with this environment

1. Frontend Angular
2. MyApi1
3. MyApi2
4. Sharepoint Online

Each element has an clientid recorded on AAD

Frontend can access to Mypi1 and MyApi2 
I want to use the OnBehalfOf to access Sharepoint with MyApi1 (I use Pnp Library)

I need the authenticated user on frontend to be recognized on all environments

I read in other post that I have to request 3 tokens

1. token from frontend, with scope MyApi1
2. token from frontend, with scope MyApi2
3. token from frontend, with scope sharepoint scope

Is there another solution, with only one request?

Answer (score 0):

The [OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of-Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) is the solution you are looking for which is covered in detail under the [Web API that calls an API Scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-web-api-call-api-overview).

You basically call MyApi1 with the token intended for it, which in turn requests for a new token to call Sharepoint Online (delegated permission should be defined in the app registration and consented for) and then makes the request.